# Local DBMS for wince (which works with lazarus)

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have to start a pocket application. I have choose Lazarus for developing it, coz it is pascal based and free.

But in dbms stage, i have limits with it.

anyway. Firebird server doesnt work on locally at wince.

at now im using dbf iii+ but it has no sql command support. do you have any idea ? Do you know a good component for connect mssql compact edition on wince ?

Regards.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations/links to third-party tools, resources, or external web sites are off-topic here. (Recommendations are opinion based, and links to external sites can disappear or be off-line, and they're not searchable here.) Google and Bing both specialize in searching for things and returning links to the results of that search. Good luck.

Comment: i just notices that there are good programmrs here and maybe they can give a good advice.

anyway. ill care about this rule.

Comment: If you don't "care about the rule" (want to follow the guidelines), don't ask questions here. Complying with them is not optional, and failing to do so can end up causing your account to be suspended or even banned. Read the [help] for more information about what types of questions are (and are not) proper to ask here. This is not an "advice" site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072/is-there-a-delphi-freepascal-bittorrent-library

there are a lot questions like this in this site. so i think the rule should newer then these.

Comment: The fact that questions exist previously does not mean it's still allowed. Guidelines here change over time; what used to be allowed is not necessarily true now. The **current guidelines** say your question is not appropriate here. There are lots of old questions that belong on [su] now; they were posted here before that site was around. They don't belong here now. I'm not going to argue with you, though. If you want to know if the question should belong here, ask on [meta] where you should ask it. Others will tell you "Google or Bing".

Comment: Ok but this is not logical. If i ask a free pascal code for db this is allowed but select a dbms doesnt. If i cant select a dbms then how can i achieve to start code?  

anyway im not he owner of site and these dissusion is off topic. 

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Lazarus forum. There are some threads about using sqlite on Wince , with links to third party builds (even older WinCEs with armv4's) e.g:

http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,10301.msg127795.html#msg127795

http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,21304.msg124493.html#msg124493

Another option is the TDBF component that comes with FPC/Lazarus.

Comment: Thanks Marco; Im current using TDBF, but Lazarus says it is deprecated and also it has no sql support. 

So i think the Sqlite is the best solution for now.

Comment: The deprecation has been lifted due to new maintainers that emerged after the last release. It can now be used again.